How do I remove this 'zombie' emulator listed by ADB, but not by Android Studio?
When I run adb devices, it shows an offline emulator:
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
emulator-5562   offline

However, when I run Device Manager in Android Studio, it's not listed. When I try to kill the emulator with adb -s emulator-5562 emu kill, I get connection refused. When I try to get info about it with adb -s emulator-5562 shell getprop, I get "device offline".
My $HOME/.android/avd folder is empty. I can't find any sign of this emulator in my file system. I'm on a Mac.
How do I get rid of this thing?
I have a React Native project that I can't run on Android, because the expo command keeps trying to run on this mysterious offline emulator, so I'm trying to attack what I think is the root issue.

Okay, so in my case, there was another process using port 5562. Apparently adb detects active ports in port range (5555 to 5585), and if something is there, it assumes it's an emulator. This is incredibly silly.
So if you're having this issue, run netstat -anv | grep 556 to figure out what process id is on that port. Ex:
tcp4       0      0  127.0.0.1.50110        127.0.0.1.5563         ESTABLISHED  408290  146988   2988      0 00002 00000000 000000000000511f 00000080 04000900      2      0 000001

Then figure out what process it is. In my case I ran ps 2988.
Then you can decide if you're able to kill this process. By killing it, your zombie emulator goes away.
